# While calling exe file from vb6, We are getting error exe stopped working

Tags: vb6

I called exe file from Vb6.

```
Shell "D:\Sample.exe RpNo, PrtVw, glngbr".
```

We are getting error exe stopped working

Comment: You should add as much information as possible. The actual error message would be a good starting point.

Comment: Those arguments look like variable names, if thats the case they are not interpolated - you would need to concat them into a string ...

Answer (score 0):

I meant to post this as a comment but don't have enough rep to do that.
First of all `Shell "D:\Sample.exe RpNo, PrtVw, glngbr"` I think the only part of the name of the program you are trying to open is only `"D:\Sample.exe"` and the rest without the "" quotes so you can try `Shell "D:\Sample.exe", RpNo, PrtVw, glngbr`
Secondly try opening the program you want to open with the shell statement and see if you get the same error because getting that error should have nothing to do with the program you used to open it the error would be coming from the program "Sample.exe" also what is `RpNo, PrtVw, glngbr` I've never seen that before, and tried that myself and it didn't work at all, try these out and I hope this helps.